# Meteor Application Fails to Find Fibers Binary; Yet NPM Built a Different One

Tags: gcc, npm, meteor, fibers

I am deploying my Meteor bundle to a similar Ubuntu 18.04 system as development.  After running meteor (starting the application), I get the following error:

```
## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
`/opt/docgen/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-57-glibc/fibers.node` is missing.
Try running this to fix the issue: /usr/bin/node /opt/docgen/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build
Error: Cannot find module '/opt/docgen/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-57-glibc/fibers'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Yet, npm install (and calling node build.js) built a binary of a different name for fibers:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xxx-xx:/opt/docgen/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers$ node build.js 
`linux-x64-72-glibc` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
```

Node version in dev and production:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xxx-3xxx-xx-xxx-xx:/opt/docgen/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers$ node -v
v12.16.1
```

npm version:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xxx-xx:/opt/docgen/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers$ npm -v
6.14.5
```

Comment: Which Meteor version? And how did you install it?

Comment: Maybe I juts get this wrong but `After running meteor ...` sounds like you installed Meteor on the production server. However, you should not install Meteor but `node` run your app bundle (built via `meteor build` command) using plain NodeJs.

Comment: @Jankapunkt  No, I just use Node to run it.  However I do have meteor installed on production server -- just don't use it.  Still I don't see why a new version of meteor on production server never used would make any difference.

Comment: @FredStark To clarify version, I use Meteor 1.10.2; however just use Node as was mentioned to run in production.  I upgraded Meteor recently and now I happen to get these errors on build (building tarball) as well:

`Unable to resolve some modules:    "internal/bootstrap/loaders" in /home/ubuntu/environment/docgen/node_modules/esm/esm.js (web.browser.legacy)

                                              
If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:
                                              
  meteor npm install --save internal`

Comment: It can make a difference If you use the meteor's builtin npm vs npm from sources.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I use npm (v. 6.14.5) to do an npm install; and don't do a meteor npm install in production.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I also tried to add a newer version of fibers to my dev build with meteor npm install before building in production - just to see if that would trigger a change in the dependency.  But no difference.

Do you know how I would track where that binary file requirement is coming from?  I need to track it down to figure out what is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appears to have been entirely caused by starting the application with Supervisor  (Is supervisor unaware of some aspects of meteor?).  Starting the application with systemd produces no such error as below.

````
Jun 17 05:06:55 ip-172-31-54-3 systemd[1]: Started AiLanthus Doc App.
Jun 17 05:06:56 ip-172-31-54-3 ailanthusdocs[31873]: Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
Jun 17 05:06:56 ip-172-31-54-3 ailanthusdocs[31873]: While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
Jun 17 05:06:56 ip-172-31-54-3 ailanthusdocs[31873]: approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
Jun 17 05:06:56 ip-172-31-54-3 ailanthusdocs[31873]: In order to use the native implementation instead, run
Jun 17 05:06:56 ip-172-31-54-3 ailanthusdocs[31873]:   meteor npm install --save bcrypt
Jun 17 05:06:56 ip-172-31-54-3 ailanthusdocs[31873]: in the root directory of your application.
Jun 17 05:08:15 ip-172-31-54-3 ailanthusdocs[31873]: Before create temp file
Jun 17 05:08:15 ip-172-31-54-3 ailanthusdocs[31873]: Source Type: Filed Complaint
Jun 17 05:08:15 ip-172-31-54-3 ailanthusdocs[31873]: Matter ID: Sw9TS7tknvfuY7toB
Jun 17 05:08:17 ip-172-31-54-3 ailanthusdocs[31873]: It's saved!```
````

Comment: @Jankapunkt a cautionary tale on Supervisor.

Answer (score 1):

The number in the filename's binary is the ABI (application binary interface) version aka `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` on [this table](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)

Version 72 is Node 12, so it checks out that when you build fibers with Node 12, you get the `linux-x64-72-glibc` binary.

I'm guessing you are using Meteor 1.6 - 1.8, which uses Node 8

Node 8 uses ABI 57, which is what it's asking for. So you want to build fibers with Node 8 to get the right binary.

Note that this shouldn't be necessary for a working Meteor install, so I would start by reinstalling Meteor before manually rebuilding it's dependencies.

Comment: I'm using Meteor 1.10.2, so that strange that it is attempting to find that old node module version.  When I do build fibers with Node 8, then try to run my application, I begin getting the error "Meteor requires Node v12.0.0 or later."  So I am at a loss -- sort of stuck between version.

Comment: That is weird then... Have you tried re-installing Meteor?

Comment: Yes, I re-installed meteor, clearing previous versions.  Then I rebuilt the tarball and transferred it to the server with the same result.

Comment: it could be my meteor build is somehow breaking even on development server.  When I build I get this passing error:

`Unable to resolve some modules:

  "internal/bootstrap/loaders" in /home/ubuntu/environment/docgen/node_modules/esm/esm.js (web.browser.legacy)`

However, running to install the package:  meteor --save internal doesn't work.  This is after upgrading meteor recently.